# Creating names for elements created by an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

For a project I'm working on, I created a simplified version of the UI Bootstrap Calendar widget.

[Plunker of my Simplified Calendar, and how I'm using it, is here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ElDYWkz5Bo7c0BfgoYTU)

One interesting aspect of the UI Bootstrap calendar, is that even though it goes onto a `input[text]`, it still produces a `date` validation in the `$error` dictionary for a form controller, just as if I had specified an `input[date]` element in my DOM.

However, there's a catch with numerous sub-catches.  One thing you'll notice right away in my plunker's DOM is that I've specified error spans for times when the given date fields are not actually dates (try entering something ridiculous like 'cat' for a value!)  If you enter something that isn't a date, those should appear, but they don't.

I've tried a few things to expose the markup being created to the name field of the parent:

1. `$transclude` set to false, such that the `<calendar></calendar>` tags get replaced with the contents of the `calendar` directive's template, with a `name` attribute specified.  This "works", except that said input is wrapped in a span that has a class necessary to look correct using the Bootstrap styling framework.
2. Directly creating a `name` attribute in the `calendar` directive's input field with a binding, like so*:

   `app.directive('mustPrecedeDate', [
       function () {
           return {
               restrict: 'E',
               template: '<input type="text" name="{{ someName }}" />',
               scope: {},
               controller: 'calendarCtrl',
               link: function () {}
           };
       }
   };`
3. Writing `link` code to explicitly find the input that is a child of the `calendar` generated markup, and assign it a `name` attribute.  Both 2 and 3 failed, because apparently that's not really something that can be done (I can't find the SO question that was the source of that discovery.)

This leads to my **Question**: in what way can I get a name down to the input element, such that validation results can be reported to the `$error` dictionary, so that I can give my users helpful validation messages?

*: Apparently, code blocks with the 'four spaces from the left' formatting don't behave well with numbered lists, so I had to use back-quote code notation to get the text to format halfway correctly.  Please feel free to correct my formatting, if I haven't found a bug in the markdown setup SO uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #3 thing needed to be tried a bit harder!

I was able to get a name on the input by adding the following code into my link function:

```
var inputElement = elem.find('input');
inputElement.attr('name', inputName);
```

...Where `inputName` is scraped from the attributes list.  I was able to get the `inputName` down to the generated `input[text]` field by using a `compile` function as below.

```
app.directive('calendar', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: false,
            scope: {},
            template:
                '<span class="input-group">'
                    + '<input class="form-control" required '
                        + 'type="text" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" '
                        + 'data-ng-model="dt" data-ng-click="toggle($event)" '
                        + 'data-ng-change="updateParentProperty()" '
                        + 'datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" is-open="isOpen" />'
                    + '<span class="input-group-btn">'
                        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="toggle($event)">'
                            + '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'
                        + '</button>'
                    + '</span>'
                + '</span>',
            controller: 'calendarCtrl',
            compile: function(elem, attrs) {
                var inputName = attrs.inputName;

                var inputElement = elem.find('input');
                inputElement.attr('name', inputName);

                // Compile returns a Link function!
                return function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                    var modelName = attrs.ngModel;

                    scope.parentProperty = modelName;
                    scope.dt = scope.$parent[modelName];
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);
```